# Call functional Component on button click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component inside which I have a button. I want to call a functional component when that button is clicked.

When we click Submit button the Preview button shows up and when the user clicks the preview button then Preview functional component is called.

```
const Form =(props)=>{

handlePreview=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    return <Preview/>
  }

return(
<input name="email" type="text"/>
<button type="submit" onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button><br/>
  {props.render&& 
   <button type="submit" onClick={handlePreview}>Preview</button>
  }

)
}
```

When I click the Submit button the Preview Button shows up but when I click the Preview Button it doesnt navigate to the `<Preview>` functional component

Comment: You should include your `Preview` component into the `Form` if you wish to render them conditionally, and control via `state`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To render component you should return it from function `Form`. If you return any component from event handler it will be ignored.

So to show `<Preview/>` component you should create local state. In functional components it can be done with [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) like below

```
const Form =(props)=>{
    const [isPreviewShown, setPreviewShown] = useState(false);

    handlePreview=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        setPreviewShown(true); // Here we change state
    }

    return(
        <input name="email" type="text"/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button><br/>
        {props.render&& 
            <button type="submit" onClick={handlePreview}>Preview</button>
        }
        {isPreviewShown && <Preview/>}

    )
}
```

Comment: Before sharing answers in `hooks`, I suggest to clarify on the ReactJS version that OP is using because many ReactJS projects still doesn't support `hooks`, just in case OP wondering why your answer isn't working. (I've upvoted btw)